# Javascript action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have few generated text fields. I want to show datepicker on text field click.

```
<!-- text fields -->
<input id="id_validity_set-0-valid_until" name="validity_set-0-valid_until" type="text" />
<input id="id_validity_set-1-valid_until" name="validity_set-1-valid_until" type="text" />
<input id="id_validity_set-2-valid_until" name="validity_set-2-valid_until" type="text" />

<!-- jquery code -->
$(document).on("click", "input[type='text']", function() {
  $( this ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ' });
});
```

When I click first time, nothing happens but if I click second time into text field datepicker shows itself. How to make datepicker show on first click? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just

```
$( "input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ' });
```

you dont need to use `click` method

demo

```js
$( "input" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="id_validity_set-0-valid_until" name="validity_set-0-valid_until" type="text" />
<input id="id_validity_set-1-valid_until" name="validity_set-1-valid_until" type="text" />
<input id="id_validity_set-2-valid_until" name="validity_set-2-valid_until" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
       $("input[type = 'text']").datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd '
     }); 

 });
```

Comment: instead of binding datepicker to the click event you can bind it when document is ready

Comment: But my code specifies where to write this code. if you write it out of socument ready it won't work. and this code will work only for input type specified for text.

Comment: OK - well, *I'm trying to help you by coaching* - so I see your point.  **Edit your answer** to explain that, and while you are editing, format your code a bit.  Then it's a good answer.  That way, future visitors to this question might upvote your answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting @cale_b