# Jquery won't work til 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling this code:

```
function LickEx(pickID){
    alert('yo');
    $(pickID).datepicker({
        format : "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose : true
    });
}
```

With: `onClick="LickExpDt('#example2');"`

The 'alert' fires every time, but the '.datepicker' will only fire if I click on it once, click somewhere else, then click on it a 2nd time (along with the 'alert) .. then it acts like normal.
I tried wrapping the function in a  `$(document).ready(function () {` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function LickEx(pickID){
        alert('yo');
        $(pickID).datepicker({
            format : "mm/dd/yyyy",
            autoclose : true
        });
    }
});
```

Nothing fires and I get a "Uncaught TypeError: LickEx is not a function"
I need to call LickEx this way so that I can pass the variable in as a parameter (it's the ID of the input box)
is there a way to pass a variable of the ID of input box being clicked on with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $([put_var_here]).datepicker({
        format : "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose : true
    });
});
```

OR fix the original?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript action on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923682/javascript-action-on-click)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just have a class on the element(s) for which you want to add the date picker functionality ?

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
```

The reason it only works on the second click in your case is that you are attaching the datepicker, only when you click on that element. So it takes an additional click to see it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, using a class: ("class=datepicker") and $('.datepicker').datepicker({....and it wouldn't fire at all ... seeme like the datepicker script only works with id's

Comment: @Jen2020 Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The first click just binds the `datepicker` to the element - the second click actually activates it. That's why you don't see the calendar until that second click.

You will need to bind the element before the click.

Comment: Thing is, I'm creating a form where the user can click a button to add more of these input boxes to the page to fill out. So, I don't know how many boxes there will be, so how could I bind them? That's why I was approaching the problem the other way, trying to push the ID in as a parameter.

Comment: You can bind them as you add them to the page.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `#` in front of ID name and `.` for class name.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pickID').datepicker({
        format : "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose : true
    });
});
```